# How to send a group of command in background

Tags: shell-scripting, init.d, daemon

I'm writing my own generic init script, I've taken strategies from here and there and come up with

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT;
until $DAEMON $DAEMONOPTS  > /var/log/${NAME}.log 2>&1 & wait ; do
  echo "Server '$NAME' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.."  > /var/log/${NAME}.log 2>&1 & echo $!
  sleep 1
done
```

It kills the child process correctly on stop, it restart the service if dies etc.

Now I have to run that piece of code as a background job instead of directly in start)

The easy solution that works and I tested already would be to move this part in its own script and & it.

However I was wondering if there was a way to group these commands and send them in background, without having a second shell script to move around. Ideally I wanted to make this a gist so it should all be in a single file.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a shell script, you can group any sequence of commands in a subshell by using `( cmd; cmd )` and then put that subshell in the background with `&` as you already know; e.g. using your example codee:

```
(
  trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT;
  until $DAEMON $DAEMONOPTS  > /var/log/${NAME}.log 2>&1 & wait ; do
    echo "Server '$NAME' crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.."  > /var/log/${NAME}.log 2>&1 & echo $!
    sleep 1
  done
) &
```

Though I have to say your `until ... sleep` notion to keep the daemon running is a bit odd.  Not sure I would want the daemon to endless restart in the event of **any failure**.  Perhaps at least check the exit code and only restart if it exited "uncleanly".  Even then, if it dies because of a configuration file syntax error (assuming it has such a thing), that will also cause it to enter an endless restart loop.

Comment: thanks! well I pan to use this for a minecraft server I set up for my friends that leak memory and crashes every now and then. nothing I can do about it, and it is just to automate the routine of starting pageant, connecting, people can't play if I'm not available etc.